# How to print out all event-names from Eventreference | MDN page with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops

Im new to JavaScript and my question is how can i print out all event-names on the console.log from this [Event reference | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) page

So far I managed to print out all event-names targeting with this line of code `var table = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr a");` but the problem is code prints also the **a** tag values from **FiredFrom** column.

Is anybody can help me with that?

So far my looping code looks like this:

```
var table = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr a");
```

```
var i = 0;
var sum =v 0;
while (i < table.length) {
    console.log(table[i].innerHTML)
    i++;
}
```

Comment: `var sum =v 0;` -> syntax error. Is this what for?

Comment: You could use: `table[i].innerText`, Then there will be no tags. But It seems your selector `"tbody tr a"` is too broad

Comment: looks like there are event names that aren't inside a table. e.g: SVG events, Database events,... etc would you like to add them as well?
But first of all what do you need this for? just curious

Comment: This is only for practicing purpuse. I had tutorial teaching how to get total number of event names from MDN Events Reference page, so I was curious how to get the event names as well. Thats it:)

Answer (score 1):

How about

Changing table selection

As

```
 var table = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr td:nth-child(1) a");
```

Comment: Thanx. That did the job:)

Comment: @RamunasNognys Accept it as a answer. So that the community gets to know this question is already answered